# SQLite Database with C# executing very slowly

Tags: c#, .net, database, sqlite

I have my `sqlite` database stored in `C:\program-name\db\db.s3db`.
I have a table `members` with about `70` records. So now there is a procedure that i have to do, which is copying all account numbers from the `members` table to the other table `act_monthly_listings`.

Its showing that it's executing but it's excrutiatingly slow. I don't know if it is because of my code. Here is a snippet:

Connection:

```
private void SetConnection()
        {
            sql_con = new SQLiteConnection
                ("Data Source=C:\\credit-union\\db\\cu.s3db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");
        }
```

On ButtonClick Code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        button1.Text = "Working Please Wait";
        string init_month = dtInit.Value.Month.ToString();
        string init_yr = dtInit.Value.Month.ToString();

        SetConnection();
        sql_con.Open();

        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select ec_no from members";
        cmd.Connection = sql_con;

        DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        int count = 0;

        while (DR.Read())
        {
            DR.Read();
            this.Text = "Account : " + DR.GetInt32(0).ToString();
           string SQL = "INSERT INTO act_monthly_listings (year,month,act) VALUES ("+ init_yr + "," + init_month + "," + DR.GetInt32(0).ToString() + ")";
           //Clipboard.SetText(SQL)
           if (ExecuteQuery(SQL))
           {
               count++;
           }


        }

        if(count > 0){
            MessageBox.Show("Accounts Initialized!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }else{
            MessageBox.Show("Initialization Failed!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        sql_con.Close(); 
    }
```

Comment: That may because of `while`, why you don't use`INSERT INTO -SELECT ` to compy all of them in one shoot .

Comment: If it did work you'd only get every other row because you call `Read()` twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because of `while` you are executing `insert` query equal to row count which make your program run very slow so this is better to use
 `INSERT INTO-SELECT` like:

```
     string init_month = dtInit.Value.Month.ToString();
     string init_yr = dtInit.Value.Month.ToString();
     SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
     cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO act_monthly_listings (year,month,act) select @y,@m,ec_no from members"; 
     cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@y", init_yr ));
     cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@m", init_month ));
     cmd.Connection = sql_con;
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

all the rows inserted in one shoot, while you are using `while` until `reader.Read()` pointer arrived to last row the `DataReader` is connecting with DB (Need to alive connection) that may make connection pooling slow plus you are executing a query per `Read` avoid this, 
suppose you have a million record then what happened by your code?